# A closed 1-form as a potential of electromagnetic field?

Tags: general-relativity

With first variation of an action (my action is formed naturally by scalar curvature of a semi-Riemannian transitive lie algebroid which I used as a framework for forces unification). I derived an equation that shows a 2-form must be identical to zero. It means that the one-form of electromagnetic field must be closed. Is it possible possible according to physics theories?

Comment: Yes. Gauge fields/connections with zero curvature are called *flat*. What do you mean with "physically possible"? An empty universe without waves obviously has vanishing electromagnetic field strength.

Comment: What action? Did you bother to include currents in your action? And even if you didn't, you shouldn't get $F_{\mu \nu} = 0$ as a result, since electromagnetic waves can still propagate freely in the absence of sources (so I kind of disagree with the comment above by @ACuriousMind) unless you fix the boundary conditions appropriately.

Comment: @Hindsight: I said "universe *without waves*".

Comment: @ACuriousMind you did, my bad.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): To reopen this question please include formula for action.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you took the action for the free E/M field

$$ S [A] = - \frac{1}{4} \int d^4 x F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} $$

and derived its Euler-Lagrange equations with respect to $F_{\mu \nu}$. This would obviously give you $F_{\mu \nu} = 0$ as a result since $F$ is only contained in the Lagrangian without derivatives.

Instead, you should variate $S[A]$ with respect to the gauge connection $A_{\mu} (x)$. This would give you the Maxwell equations for the empty space:

$$ \partial_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu} = 0. $$

The most generic solution is a superposition of propagating E/M waves. In order to get the Coulomb potential, you should introduce currents in your action like this:

$$ S[A] = - \frac{1}{4} \int d^4 x F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} + \int d^4 x A_{\mu} (x) j^{\mu} (x). $$